# Drupal 7,x baidu map loaded but not displaying

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, baidu

I am trying [baidu map](https://www.drupal.org/project/baidu_map) module on Drupal 7.x . It is not displaying the map from some reason.

The map is there. Once I switch the view(satellite view, normal view), the map starts to show up.

Open the firebug and I find that Baidu is returning a piece of JavaScript code containing "document.write" which does the the painting of the map as it seems.

But this is the farthest I can go, I don't know how to touble shoot this.

Any help would be appreciated.

http://d7.jusfeel.cn/node/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to the zoom level when the map is loaded. Please reduce one zoom level and check it again its working for zoom level of 15. but your default zoom level is 16.

It may also be the case that you have not set the default zoom level. Check after setting the default zoom level.